# How to prevent page load event fire on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have dynamically created button in c#, all button is bind to page on page load event of page

Now, when I press any of button from them then first of all it again bind all controls and then it fire it's click event

How can I stop that re-binding of control when I click button?

Comment: Show your page load code

Comment: what you want on those button's click? client side event?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            }
             else
             {
              fillquotes();
              }
          }

        fillquotes()
         {
         //dynamicaaly create the button 
          msg.OnClientClick=1;
          
         }
          msg_click()
          {
           ------
          {

when msg button clicks 
1)pageload
2)msg_click()
3)pageload 
4)msg_click()

Comment: clientside
 function lnkmsg(id) {
__doPostBack('<%= btnMsg.UniqueID %>', "");
}

Comment: Edit the question and add the code in question.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            }
             else
             {
              fillquotes();
              }
          }

        fillquotes()
         {
         //dynamicaaly create the button 
          msg.OnClientClick="lnkmsg(" + i + ")";
                   }
          btnMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
           ------
          }
client side:
 function lnkmsg(id) {
__doPostBack('<%= btnMsg.UniqueID %>', "");
}


when msg button clicks 
1pageload
2msg_click()
3pageload 
4msg_click()

Comment: Please help me i am wating for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Very easy, just catching the value of the `isPostBack` attribute of `Page`:

```
protected void Page_Load(...) {
  if (!Page.isPostBack) {
    //features to run only once
  } else {
    //features to run on each post back
  }
}
```

Related links:

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If using WebForms PageLoad will always be run on postbacks / event submitting to the server. (It's part of the life cycle for a web form page)

But you can use the [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to check wether it's a postback or the first time the page is hit, and only do your binding if it is not Page.IsPostBack.